# Two stars in a Prolog list

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

what are the two stars in a list?

```
[53, 5, 1, 53, 97, 115, 53, 50, 52, 121, 55, 56, 55, 97, 4, 1, 98, **]
```

I tried searching but no success.

Comment: Newer versions of SWI no longer use `**`

Answer (score 9):

The stars indicate that the term contains itself, e.g.

```
?- X = f(X).
X = f(**).

?- L = [53, L].
L = [53, **].
```

This is the case at least in older versions of SWI-Prolog.
See also https://lists.iai.uni-bonn.de/pipermail/swi-prolog/2009/001707.html.